# Poles of Complex Functions or One-Forms?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms

The function $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1-z}}$ with branch cuts chosen so that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb C-[0,1]$ has a pole at infinity according to [this](http://math.arizona.edu/~faris/methodsweb/branch.pdf) walkthrough of a branch cut contour integration.

But rather it seems like what I should say is that the one-form $f(z)dz$ has a pole at infinity, since without the $dz$ the function $f(\frac 1w)$ doesn't blowup at $w=0$. Can someone explain what is going on?

I've also read elsewhere that one-forms are automatically coordinate-independent. I'm not sure what exactly is meant by this, but perhaps it is related? That is, we should really talk about poles of objects that are coordinate-independent as opposed to functions which are just one-forms with respect to some implicit choice of coordinates and the differential suppressed -- or something like that.  I would appreciate an answer to both questions.

Answer (score 0):

That function doesn't have a pole at infinity. The form does. The reason why you look at the form is because that (the form) is what is inside the integral.

For example. Take the function $g(z)=1$. It doesn't have a pole anywhere. It is constant. But $1\text{d}z=-\frac{1}{w^2}\text{d}w$ has a pole at infinity.

An important observation is that the residue of a function (if you want to define residue of a function) might be non-zero at a regular point, when that point is infinity.

This is why the theory looks nicer when you instead define residues for forms, instead of for functions. At a regular point of a form, the residue is zero.

In the note you linked, they say "the trick is to realize that there is a pole of $f(z)\text{d}z$". There is no trick, or if anything the trick is the use of the change of coordinates $w=1/z$. You don't even need to think about any poles of anyone. You want to compute $\int_C f(z)\text{d}z$. Cauchy's theorem is not applicable to this integral. You change variable to $w=1/z$ such that you can apply Cauchy's theorem. When you change variable you do get a function $1/\sqrt{1-w}$ for which Cauchy's theorem is applicable to the contour integral $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-w}}\frac{\text{d}w}{w}$. You use it, and you are done. No definition of pole necessary.

Comment: So should one talk about poles / residues of one-forms or functions? Are they mutually compatible or does one generalize the other? We normally talk about things like residues of functions for things like Cauchy's theorem, but how do one-forms fit in with that? And would you elaborate or supply references for what you mean by the theory looks nicer when you define residues for forms?

Comment: @ntropy You can talk about poles and residues of both functions and forms. The residue is the integral along an arbitrarily small circle around the point (this is the same wording for both functions and for forms). They define the same concept of residue. By "the theory looks nicer" I meant only the result "the residue at a regular point is zero". This is true for forms but not for functions as we saw in the case of residue at $\infty$.